# I am found 'subject' is of type 'unknown'. error during the npm start but code is run and working how to resolved it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, react-typescript

```
Object.entries(APIData).map(([key, subject], i) => {
  return (
    <div className="id-result" key={i}>
      <div id="heading-result">
        <h2 key={i} className="heder-result">{subject.title}</h2>
        {/* <img id="pdficon" src={pdficon} alt="download pdf" height="20px" /> */}
        <Button className="download-button"><PDFReader /></Button>
      </div>
      <hr className="hr-result" />
      {/* <p  className="para-result" key={i}>{subject.para}</p>   */}
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: subject.para }}>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
```

I am facing error on subject that 'subject' is of type 'unknown'.

Comment: What is the type of APIData ?